# Check if flags are set and not set in MySQL query

Tags: php, bitwise-operators, flags

I have two flags (64 and 32) and I need to check if "64" is set and "32" is NOT set inside a "MySQL column value" (quest_template.Flag).

The value of the column quest_template.Flag is: "824183885".

Therefore I use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM quest_template
WHERE quest_template.ID > 0
AND 64 & quest_template.Flag AND 32 != quest_template.Flag
```

At the moment I have the problem that the query just checks if the "64" is set but not if the "32" is NOT set.

Where is the mistake in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `&` to mask with a bit flag. Then just check if it's `0` or `1`.

```
SELECT * FROM quest_template
WHERE quest_template.ID > 0
AND 64 & quest_template.Flag = 1
AND 32 & quest_template.Flag = 0
```